# Shared instances and global variables

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, spotify

I am using the Spotify SDK and have followed the instructions from this tutorial: https://medium.com/@elonrubin/ios-spotify-sdk-swift-3-0-tutorial-b629af4b889d
The guide uses this function to initialize the SpotifyPlayer:

```
func initializeSpotifyPlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
    if self.spotifyPlayer == nil {
        self.spotifyPlayer = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
        self.spotifyPlayer!.playbackDelegate = self
        self.spotifyPlayer!.delegate = self
        try! spotifyPlayer!.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
        self.spotifyPlayer!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
    }
}
```

On the third line, you can see that it makes the SpotifyPlayer a shared instance. How would I access this same spotifyPlayer from another ViewController/file?

Comment: You should look inside `SPTAudioStreamingController` and see what `sharedInstance()` is doing. My guess would be there is an object that hold public props. for `spotifyPlayer` that is assessable through  `SPTAudioStreamingController.shared`

Comment: All of the documentation and definitions are in Obj-C, so I can't make much sense of it. But heres what it says: `/**
 Access the shared 'SPAudioStreamingController' instance
 @return Returns the shared 'SPAudioStreamingController' instance
 */
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;`. Do you understand that?

Comment: Look as per my guess sharedInstance is nothing but a singleton class. so there is no need to worry about the instance. Moreover if you want a same name throughout the app then create this instance in AppDelegate & access in the app

Comment: Just call `SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()?.whatever`